# Configuration is missing in lunch .jason running app on real device using usb debugging

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, usb-debugging

developer option is On- in my phone the same as USB debugging...
the phone is connected and known in vs code
when I choose my phone to run the app. I got this error:
how to Fix it?
[image]

Comment: please explain more in detail. thanks

Answer (score 0):

at the left sidebar of vs code you can create new configuration file, run and debug section

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'
   > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
      > Failed to transform arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-

Comment: saeed unfotunately I get a Build failue error after....please give me a hint to find where is wrong?

Comment: did you add Configuration json?

Comment: I did'n find it on (Run  -> add configuration) ...i added  just select (flutter :attach to the device ) option. but this mortal error came up.